# vertical and horizontal centered sticky sidebar with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, fixed, sidebar

I am trying to make a sticky sidebar where the navigation is both centered vertical and horizontal. Which is super easy with flexbox. But when I added the "position: fixed" and "height: 100%", it is no longer centered on the horizontal side. Is there any other why to do this and still have it centered?

```css
.sidebar {
  background: #223556;
  width: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<aside class="sidebar flex justify-center align-center">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="index.php"><span class="sf sf-home-o"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="about.php"><span class="sf sf-user-o"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="projects.php"><span class="sf sf-code-o"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php"><span class="sf sf-envelope-3-o"></span></a></li>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

Comment: width:100% instead of width:100px

Comment: Could you just share a working snippet or fiddle?

Comment: I've made this. https://jsfiddle.net/a2cdkt92/1/
But it seems it's centered in this one.

Here's the thing I'm working on.. Is it just on my screen there's a problem?
http://helenaengel.com/portfolio/index.php

Comment: Position absolute and fixed remove the elements from the flow of the doucument and thus are not affected by flex box

Comment: I've added an answer and also tested it on your website. It because you use bottom-margin. This is fine, except you shouldn't be using it on the last element. As you can see on here, the bottom-margin should be removed from the last one: https://snag.gy/EdiKHC.jpg

Answer (score 0):

please check below example

```css
.sidebar{

  width: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}
.sidebar .nav{
    background: #223556;
}
.table{
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.table-cell{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<aside class="sidebar flex justify-center align-center">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell">
   
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="index.php"><span class="sf sf-home-o"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php"><span class="sf sf-user-o"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="projects.php"><span class="sf sf-code-o"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php"><span class="sf sf-envelope-3-o"></span></a></li>
      </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
    </aside>
```

Comment: is it just me or this isn't what the op's have asked ?

Comment: I'm only talking about the navigation inside the sidebar. The side should be all the way to the left. Not centered.

Answer (score 0):

```css
   

 

.sidebar {
    background: #223556;
    width: 100px;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    }
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="index.php"><span class="sf sf-home-o">Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="about.php"><span class="sf sf-user-o">About</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="projects.php"><span class="sf sf-code-o">Projects</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php"><span class="sf sf-envelope-3-o">Contact</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The sidebar items are not centered on your website because you use a margin-bottom on all the elements. You shouldn't be using it on the last element.
You could make use of the `:last-child` selector and remove the `bottom-margin`. See this [screenshot](https://snag.gy/EdiKHC.jpg)

https://jsfiddle.net/a2cdkt92/3/

I've done that on your example on fiddle see the link above.

If you add the following to your css of the website it should be solved

```
.nav li:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's fixed. I must've been blind.

Comment: Nice, no problem. Please mark the answer as the correct one so other people can find it easier.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
.nav li:not(:last-child){
  margin-bottom: 90px;
}
```

I hope this will fix the issue.